# dev_appserver ndb entities missing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using Google App Engine and have created entities in the ndb store in the cloud.

However, when I run `dev_appserver.py` I do not see these entities in the local datastore viewer located at `http://localhost:8000/datastore`

How do I sync entities in the cloud and locally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sentence: You don't.

The local devserver isn't meant to be used online, or meant to be used in complement to the App Engine. It's a testing/debugging tool and not meant in any way to connect to the cloud.

The best you can do is to [download your datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#backing_up_data) and link it into your devserver using a script that will read your downloaded datastore and push it to your devserver.